# How can I use Sidekiq's timestamp parameter inside the perform method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

When calling the `perform_at` function this way:

```
Worker.perform_at(timestamp, param_1, param_2)
```

According to what I have seen, the `timestamp` here is only used by the Worker to schedule the job. The args of the Worker's perform method start from param_1, ...

How can we use the `timestamp` value inside the perform method of the Worker?

Comment: Passing it as additional argument? `Worker.perform_at(timestamp, param_1, param_2, timestamp)`

Comment: @Зелёный I was hoping I wouldn't need to duplicate it.

Comment: it's most simple way, so it the better way, dont make things complex.